# ValueError: Shapes (7, 7, 6, 64) and (64, 3, 7, 7) are incompatible when running train.py file

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I have done preprocessing the dataset files and converted them to .png file by running preprocess.py and preprocess_2d_images.py respectively. After that I organized the resultant png files in the dataset_brats19. Here is the link of the github repo of the code below

[GitHub Repository of DeepSeg Code from Author](https://github.com/razeineldin/DeepSeg)

According to the Readme file of the following GitHub repo I tried to run the train.py but when I try to run the train.py , it throws me these errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Study Materials/Study/4th Year/7th Semester/CSE 4000/Code/DeepSeg/train.py", line 98, in <module> main()

File "D:/Study Materials/Study/4th Year/7th Semester/CSE 4000/Code/DeepSeg/train.py", line 71, in main load_model=config['load_model'])

model = get_deepseg_decoder(decoder_name, n_classes, encoder, input_height, input_width, depth, filter_size, encoder_name, up_layer, trainable)
  File "D:\Study Materials\Study\4th Year\7th Semester\CSE 4000\Code\DeepSeg\models.py", line 62, in get_deepseg_decoder

decoder = get_unet_modified_decoder(n_classes, encoder, input_height, input_width, depth, filter_size, encoder_name, up_layer, trainable)
  File "D:\Study Materials\Study\4th Year\7th Semester\CSE 4000\Code\DeepSeg\decoders.py", line 94, in get_unet_modified_decoder img_input, levels = encoder(input_height=input_height, input_width=input_width, depth=depth, filter_size=filter_size, encoder_name=encoder_name)

File "D:\Study Materials\Study\4th Year\7th Semester\CSE 4000\Code\DeepSeg\encoders.py", line 928, in get_densenet121_encoder
    Model(img_input, x).load_weights(weights_path)

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DeepSeg-master\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper
    return load_function(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DeepSeg-master\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1230, in load_weights
    f, self.layers, reshape=reshape)

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DeepSeg-master\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 1237, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DeepSeg-master\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2960, in batch_set_value
    tf_keras_backend.batch_set_value(tuples)

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DeepSeg-master\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3323, in batch_set_value
    x.assign(np.asarray(value, dtype=dtype(x)))

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DeepSeg-master\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 819, in assign
    self._shape.assert_is_compatible_with(value_tensor.shape)

File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DeepSeg-master\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 1110, in assert_is_compatible_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (7, 7, 6, 64) and (64, 3, 7, 7) are incompatible
```

Please give me some instructions on the further execution flow of the code if anyone did before. I am using Python 3.7 and Tensorflow 2.1.0

Comment: Please, can anybody help me?

Comment: Usually in Keras, Conv layers data format will be `channels_first` , but in Tensorflow by default it is `channels_last`. In the code which you are trying to replicate check if they have used direct keras import or import keras from Tensorflow and follow the same and try. Thanks!